# Angular ng-repeat compiled element

Tags: angularjs

I'm having some trouble with angular getting confused on compiled vs non-compiled templates.

```
  <div>
    <condition ng-repeat="condition in conditions"></condition>
  </div>
```

Which generates the following HTML: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2064c92e990a33ffe57e

When `$scope.conditions` changes - and only the first time `$scope.conditions` changes - this code is executed in angular.js v1.2.0-2fe5a2d (didn't work with the stable release either, thus the upgrade):

```
if (block.startNode == nextNode) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    // existing item which got moved
    $animate.move(block.elements, null, jqLite(previousNode));
}
```

Where `block.startNode.nodeName == 'CONDITION'` which appears to refer to the pre-compiled template. When the code is running properly - that is every time BUT the first time - `block.startNode.nodeName == 'DIV'`. In both circumstances nextNode.nodeName == 'DIV' which, when working properly, does not $animate.move the element entirely out of the DOM. This leaves the model filled with elements while the view is not reflecting this. Is it an angular bug?

Has anyone else experienced this? Any thoughts?

** I should mention I "solved" this by changing the $$hashKey on my objects. Yes, I feel dirty. **

Comment: It's hard to get the issue you encounter. Could you provide a simplified jsfiddle / plunker that shows the problem?

Comment: I wish I could simplify the problem. It's all kinds of nested directives deep. I'm thinking that has something to do with it.

Comment: if checking for object equality use `angular.equals()`  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.equals